# Stop receiving messages from SubscriptionClient

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

How do you stop receiving messages from a subscription client set as a an event-driven message pump? I currently have some code that works however when I run two tests consecutively they second breaks. I'm fairly sure messages are still being pulled off the subscription from the first instance i created.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130336.aspx

```
OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
            options.AutoComplete = true; // Indicates if the message-pump should call complete on messages after the callback has completed processing.

            options.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1; // Indicates the maximum number of concurrent calls to the callback the pump should initiate 

            options.ExceptionReceived += LogErrors; // Enables you to be notified of any errors encountered by the message pump

            // Start receiveing messages
            Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) => // Initiates the message pump and callback is invoked for each message that is received. Calling Close() on the client will stop the pump.

                {
                    // Process the message
                    Trace.WriteLine("Processing", receivedMessage.SequenceNumber.ToString());
                }, options);
```

Comment: Did you test the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `SubscriptionClient.Close()` to stop further messages from being processed.

Also indicated in the comment in the code:

> Calling Close() on the client will stop the pump.

Comment: -1 That does not work. One last message still comes through the OnMessage callback, and throws an exception when the receiver method attempts to complete it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do two things.

First, call `subscriptionClient.Close()`, which will eventually (but not immediately) stop the message pump.

Second, on your message received callback, check if the client is closed, like so:

```
if (subscriptionClient.IsClosed)
    return;
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked and see the exact same behavior.  The message pump does NOT stop trying to process messages even when you close the subscription client.  If your message processing handler attempts to do a `.Complete` or `.Abandon` on the message, it will throw an exception though, because the client is closed.   Need a way to stop the pump guys.